# Check if a Woocommerce Hook is from API

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I have a problem like this:

I have a custom field in WooCommerce that is a flag for if the article is transferd/updated to another system.

The field/flag can be set from manualy edit the article in Woocommerce or set by the REST API by another system.

If I edit the field manualy I use this code to set it to 'no':

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'lg_set_transferd_flag', 10, 1 );
function lg_set_transferd_flag( $product_id ) {
         update_post_meta( $product_id, 'product_transferd_to_visma', 'no' );
}
```

To set it from an action in the other system I use this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_edit_product', 'lg_set_transferd_flag_from_api', 10, 1);
function lg_set_transferd_flag_from_api( $product_id ) {
      update_post_meta( $product_id, 'product_transferd_to_visma', 'yes' );
}
```

The problem is that the "woocommerce_api_edit_product" hook trigger the "woocommerce_update_product" so I end up with the flag 'no' what ever I do.

Is there a way to function on hook "woocommerce_update_product" to know that the action is from "woocommerce_api_edit_product"?